# How to filter data by array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have data array and i want to filter data by array.

Below is my array.

```
[1,3,4]
```

Below is my data

```
[
    {id: 1, content_tag: 'Test'}
    {id: 2, content_tag: 'test 1'}
    {id: 3, content_tag: 'test 2'}
    {id: 4, content_tag: 'test 3'}
]
```

I want result as like below:

```
[
    {id: 1, content_tag: 'Test'}
    {id: 3, content_tag: 'test 2'}
    {id: 4, content_tag: 'test 3'}
]
```

Comment: You have to show what you tried so far, and what issue you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Use array methods filter and include to compare two arrays

```js
let arr1 = [1,3,4]

let arr2 = [
    {id: 1, content_tag: 'Test'},
    {id: 2, content_tag: 'test 1'},
    {id: 3, content_tag: 'test 2'},
    {id: 4, content_tag: 'test 3'}
]

arr2.filter(eachElement => arr1.includes(eachElement.id))
```